# Does github mandate that you use “git” as username when ssh-ing?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I’m trying to ssh to github.com, but I’m having trouble connecting when I use a different username other than “git”, and I’m not totally sure why.  I have an `~/.ssh/config` file to tell git which private rsa key to use when I am connecting to git.  And, my knowledge of `.ssh/config` files is the following:

Let’s say I have this in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host something.github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User someuser
    IdentityFile ~/desired/private_key
```

I always thought that this means whenever I do `someuser@something.github.com`, it will ALWAYS use the file `~/desired/private_key` to connect.  Firstly – is my understanding of that correct?

Second, I have the following in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
# for work
Host my-company.github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_veritone 

# also for work, but using my username
Host company.github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User employee
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_veritone
```

The `my-company.github.com`  works, but `company.github.com` does NOT:

```
08:20 $ ssh -T git@my-company.github.com 
Hi employee! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

08:20 $ ssh -T employee@company.github.com 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is this the expected behavior? If so, then does git mandate that I use `git` as my username when I ssh?  If not, then what could be the issue that one of these does not work?

Comment: Your question asks: "does git mandate that I use `git` as my username".  No.  _git_ does not mandate this.  _GitHub_ does.

Comment: ah, that's a key distinction

Answer (score 1):

YOu always have to use the git user.  from https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/:

"All connections, including those for remote URLs, must be made as the "git" user. If you try to connect with your GitHub username, it will fail:"